# Error: no match for 'operator>>' for std::cin

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

I was coding for an exercise:

> Write a complete program that reads an integer from the user,doubles it using the doubleNumber() function,and then prints the doubled value out to the console.

```
#include <iostream>

int doubleNumber(int x)
{
    return 2*x;
}

int main()
{

    int a;
    std::cout << "Enter an integer :" ;
    std::cin >> a >> std::endl;
    std::cout << doubleNumber(a) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error that I get while compiling is:

```
error: no match for 'operator >>'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `endl;` should be `std::endl;`  And why are you using `>>` on `std::endl`?

Comment: Thank you PaulMckenzie. The code worked after correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues. You are missing the std for endl. This necessary to identify the scope since endl is from std.

Your other issue is when you are using cin, there is no need to add a std::endl. std::endl only represents the end of the line (creates a new line). The cin command takes input only and std::endl is not a variable you can put input in.

If you fix those, your program will run fine.

Fixed Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int doubleNumber(int x)
{
    return 2*x;
}

int main()
{

    int a;
    std::cout << "Enter an integer :" ;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << doubleNumber(a) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code snippets are generally only for Javascript, HTML, and others, but not for C++

Comment: Do we have a formatter for C++ code? I just used it as a wrapper for the code.

Answer (score 2):

What [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) actually does, is, writes a newline to the stream (`'\n'`), and then flushes the stream using `std::flush`, writing everything that is in the buffer to the screen.

Note that it *writes* the newline, which would mean that it is unsuitable for input, and thus shouldn't be used for such.

Also, you forgot to specify `std::` before `endl` in the second line of output.

Comment: Noted. 
Also I read that the standard library directive statement
using namespace std;
should be limited to be used inside the function, or more often the use should be like std::, I wanted to know why using it outside of a function is avoided?

Answer (score 0):

Your final endl should be std::endl;

Also take out that endl after the cin, cin only takes in values, no need to add a newline, thats for cout.

Comment: Thankyou , after correcting the code the progrma worked well.